# closing a new browser tab using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

A new tab opens up when i click a link given in a iframe. Is it possible to close these newly opened tabs by giving some controls in the iframe

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers sandbox each tab, preventing the ability to do what you're requesting.  As an example, run [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkkLc1yz/) and watch your JS console in your browser.

The code will open a new browser tab using JS so we have a little bit of control over it:

```
var x = window.open('https://www.google.com');
```

But, when we try to close it:

```
x.close();
```

In most browsers you will see an error when you attempt to control navigation or close the window in the second (sandboxed) tab.